# Why does the user get logged out on refresh? - Using Firebase Authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I've created a simple log in and sign up for a personal project of mine. However have run into some bugs as it's the first time I've actually coded something like this. Why is the user logged out on refresh? It may be due to me creating auth in the wrong way but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for any help

I've tried using setPersistence but had no luck.

Log In Page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from '/src/firebase.js'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faX } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { setPersistence, browserSessionPersistence, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'

 
export default function Login({ userLogin, setUserLogin }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof grecaptcha !== 'undefined') {
      grecaptcha.ready(() => {
        grecaptcha.render('Login-reCaptcha')
      })
    }
  },[])

  const [submitNotification,setSubmitNotification] = useState({
    show: false,
    msg: ""
  }) // notification for any responses from requests e.g form submition

  function handleInput(e) {
    setUserLogin(prevInput => {return {
      ...prevInput,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }})
  }

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e)
    if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
      setSubmitNotification(prevValue => {return{
          show: true,
          msg: "Please complete the reCaptcha!"
        }})
    } else {
      try {
        const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          userLogin.email,
          userLogin.password
        )
        if (user) {
          handleUserAuth()
          navigate("/Getting-Started")
        }
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        if (error == "FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/user-not-found).") {
          setSubmitNotification(prevValue => {return {
            show: true,
            msg: "User does not exist."
          }})
        } else if (error == "FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/wrong-password).") {
          setSubmitNotification(prevValue => {return{
            show: true,
            msg: "Your email/password is incorrect"
          }})
        } else if (error == "FirebaseError: Firebase: Access to this account has been temporarily disabled due to many failed login attempts. You can immediately restore it by resetting your password or you can try again later. (auth/too-many-requests).") {
          setSubmitNotification(prevValue => {return {
            show: true,
            msg: "User blocked, please try again later"
          }})
        }
      }
    } 
  }

  const handleUserAuth = async (e) => {
    setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("persistence ran")
      return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userLogin.email, userLogin.password)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.code)
      console.log(error.messsage)
    })
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <div className='flex justify-start items-center w-full h-24 p-4 absolute top-5 left-0'>
        <img className='h-28 hidden sm:inline-block' src='/ebayanalyticscut.png'></img>
      </div>
      <div className='h-screen flex justify-center items-center text-white font-poppins'>
        <div className='sm:bg-secondary h-[550px] w-[530px] rounded-2xl overflow-hidden p-5'>
          <form className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center' onSubmit={handleLogin}>
            <h1 className='text-3xl mb-5 font-medium'>Welcome Back!</h1>
            {submitNotification.show &&
            <div className='bg-red w-[350px] h-10 rounded-md mb-4 flex flex-row items-center p-3'>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faX} className='h-3 mr-4 mt-0.5 cursor-pointer' onClick={() => setSubmitNotification(prevValue => {return{...prevValue, show: false}})}/>
              <p className='text-lg'>{submitNotification.msg}</p>
            </div>}
            <div className='mb-6'>
            <label className='text-lg block'>Email Address</label>
            <input value={userLogin.email} autoComplete='off' name='email' type='email' className='h-10 w-[350px] rounded-xl text-black pl-2 font-medium'  onChange={handleInput}></input>
            </div>
            <div className='mb-9'>
            <label className='text-lg block'>Password</label>
            <input value={userLogin.password} autoComplete='off' name='password' type='password' className='h-10 w-[350px] rounded-xl text-black pl-2 font-medium' onChange={handleInput}></input>
            </div>
            <div id='Login-reCaptcha' className="g-recaptcha mb-6 -mt-3" data-sitekey={import.meta.env.VITE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY} data-theme="dark"></div>
            <button className='bg-accent w-[300px] h-12 rounded-2xl text-lg mb-5'>Log In</button>
            <p>Don't have an account? <Link to='/' className='underline text-accent'>Sign Up</Link></p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

App.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './index.css'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Signup from './pages/Signup'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Start from './pages/Start'
import { setPersistence, browserSessionPersistence, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from '/src/firebase.js'


export default function App() {

  const [userSignup, setUserSignup] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmpassword: ""
  })
  
  
  const [userLogin,setUserLogin] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  })
  

  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Signup 
        userSignup={userSignup} 
        setUserSignup={setUserSignup}/>}/>
        <Route path='/Login' 
        element={<Login 
        userLogin={userLogin} 
        setUserLogin={setUserLogin}/>}/>
        <Route path='/Getting-Started' 
        element={<Start 
        userLogin={userLogin}/>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It seems you're not saving your state. In ReactJS, `useState` keeps data only while the DOM is active—it doesn't persist. To keep your login/auth-token, think about using the browser's localstorage. Pairing it with redux and react-redux could be a great approach.

Comment: While you import `onAuthStateChanged`, you're not using it anywhere. So Firebase *does* likely restore the auth state, but your app is not reacting to that. See the first code snippet in : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: @Dennis the user's details are saved in state because whenever I go to another page in the app I check the state in React tools and email and password are there

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So Firebase is basically logging the user out? Will the solution to this be adding the the setPersistence to onAuthStateChanged - so while they're logged in it sets persistence?

Comment: Update: I got it work, added the following to App.jsx, however I am getting some errors in the console now: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: getModularInstance(...).setPersistence is not a function

`onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), (user) => {
    if (user) { //if logged in
      setPersistence(getAuth, browserSessionPersistence)
      .then(() => {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth, userLogin.email, userLogin.password)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.code)
        console.log(error.message)
      })
    }
  })`

Comment: "So Firebase is basically logging the user out?" No. On most browsers Firebase actually automatically persists the user credentials (in local storage) and restores them when the page/app reloads. But in that case there will be no call made to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, so you need to use `onAuthStateChanged` to detect when the sign-in has completed.